# Uncertainty relation for $S_z$ eigenstates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-spin, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator

I am content with the method of finding the uncertainty relation for $L_z$ eigenstates in a spin-1/2 system where $|\uparrow\rangle=|m=1/2\rangle$ and $|\downarrow\rangle=|m=-1/2\rangle$. I have used the fact that $[L_x,L_y]=i\hbar{L_z}$ and $L_z|\psi\rangle=m\hbar|\psi\rangle$

$$
\Delta{L_x}\Delta{L_y}\geqslant \frac{1}{2}|\langle{\psi}|[L_x,L_y]|\psi\rangle|\qquad \hbox{with}\qquad
\textstyle\frac{1}{2}|\langle{\psi}|[L_x,L_y]|\psi\rangle|=\frac{\hbar}{2}|\langle\psi|L_z|\psi\rangle|\, .
$$

For $|\psi\rangle=|nlm\rangle$ we have 
\begin{align}\frac{\hbar}{2}|\langle\psi|L_z|\psi\rangle|&=\frac{m\hbar^2}{2}\langle{nlm}|nlm\rangle \tag{1}\, ,\\
\Delta{L_x}\Delta{L_y}&\geqslant\frac{m\hbar^2}{2}\langle{nlm}|nlm\rangle=\frac{m\hbar^2}{2} \tag{2}
\end{align}
and clearly for m=1/2 we have $\Delta{L_x}\Delta{L_y}\geqslant\frac{\hbar^2}{4}$ and for m=-1/2 we have $\Delta{L_x}\Delta{L_y}\geqslant-\frac{\hbar^2}{4}$

I understand how this works however for unknown reasons I am struggling to do the same for $\Delta{S_x}\Delta{S_y}$ where $i\hbar{S_z}=[S_x,S_y]$

some guidance would be helpful, is the process the same?

Comment: The commutation relations for spin and angular momentum are exactly the same. Here $i\hbar S_z=[S_x, S_y]$. Also note that  "$L_z=m\hbar$" is something of an abuse of notation.

Comment: sorry should it be $L_z=m_l\hbar$ ?

Comment: No, $L_z$ is an operator and operators are not equal to their eigenvalues (which are numbers). You could instead write $L_z|m\rangle=\hbar m|m\rangle$.

Comment: oh I see of course I will fix that now

Comment: does $S_z|\psi\rangle=m\hbar|\psi\rangle$ ?

Comment: Actually, sorry for making my first comment rash. You're not asking about spin but explicitly for the commutation relation $S_z=[S_x,S_y]$ ? In this case you should specify what the operators $S_i$ are (since they are not spin operators). My confusion arose from the usual names $L$ for angular momentum and $S$ for spin. You named the Spin 1/2 operators $L$, which is slightly unusual.
For your last comment: That depends on what $|\psi\rangle$ is. Not all vectors are eigenstates of $S_z$.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to make sure you keep the absolute value in $\frac{1}{2}\vert\langle \psi\vert [A,B]\vert\psi\rangle\vert$.  In the specific case of your question the right hand sides of (1) and (2) should respectively be 
   \begin{align}
   &\vert m\vert\frac{\hbar^2}{2}\langle n\ell m\vert n\ell m\rangle\, ,\qquad
   \hbox{and}\qquad 
   \vert m\vert \frac{\hbar^2}{2}\, .
   \end{align}
   so the product $\Delta L_x\Delta L_y$, which is the product of two positive numbers, remains $\ge +\frac{\hbar^2}{4}$ even for the $m=-1/2$ state, not $-\frac{\hbar^2}{4}$ as you have it.
2. For kets denoted by $\vert n\ell m\rangle$, $\ell$ is often an integer so only integer values of $m$ can occur.  Thus a more appropriate version of your $\langle n\ell m\vert n\ell m\rangle$ would be $\langle\uparrow\vert\uparrow\rangle$ for the $m=1/2$ state, and $\langle\downarrow\vert\downarrow\rangle$ for the $m=-1/2$ state.  In both cases, $\Delta L_x\Delta L_y\ge \frac{\vert m\vert\hbar^2}{2}$.
3. The derivation you have provided for $L_x,L_y,L_z$ depends only on the commutations relations and so it holds for the spin operators $S_x,S_y$ and $S_z$ as they have the same commutation relations as the angular momentum operators $L_x,L_y,L_z$.